# problem with Assignment 3 , Introduction_to_Data_Science_in_Python coursera

Tags: python

I have some problem with Assignment 3 (https://github.com/AparaV/intro-to-data-science-with-python/tree/master/assignment-03). 
I expect there are no 'Nan' in result. but there are 'Nan' value.
this is my first time to study programming language. It would be great if someone could tell me what is wrong with my python code.
here is the picture of [wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0torI.png) and [result using codes below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XehkM.png)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
def answer_one():
    def energy():
        energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',sheet_name='Energy')
        energy = energy.iloc[16:243]
        energy.drop(['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'], axis ='columns',inplace=True)
        energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']

        energy = energy.replace('...',np.nan)
        energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply']*1000000

        energy = energy.replace('Republic of Korea','South Korea')
        energy = energy.replace('United States of America','United States')
        energy = energy.replace('United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland','United Kingdom')
        energy = energy.replace('China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region','Hong Kong')

        energy['Country'] =  energy['Country'].str.replace(" \(.*\)","")

        energy = energy.reset_index()
        energy = energy[['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']]
        return energy

    def GDP():
        GDP= pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv')
        s=(GDP.iloc[3].values)[:4].astype(str).tolist() + (GDP.iloc[3].values)[4:].astype(int).astype(str).tolist()
        GDP = GDP[4:]
        GDP.columns = s
        GDP = GDP[['Country Name','2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']]
        GDP.columns = ['Country','2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']

        GDP = GDP.replace('Korea, Rep.','South Korea')
        GDP = GDP.replace('Iran, Islamic Rep','Iran')
        GDP = GDP.replace('Hong Kong SAR, China','Hong Kong')
        return GDP

    def ScimEn():
        ScimEn = pd.read_excel('scimagojr-3.xlsx')
        return ScimEn

    e = energy() 
    g = GDP()
    s = ScimEn()

    df=pd.merge(e,g,how = 'outer',left_on='Country',right_on='Country')
    df=pd.merge(s,df,how='outer',left_on='Country',right_on='Country')
    df.sort_values(by=['Rank'], inplace = True)
    df.set_index('Country',inplace=True)
    res = df.head(15)
    return res
answer_one()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try apply the regex replace first then replace the country name like this.

```
    def energy():
        energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', sheet_name='Energy')
        energy = energy.iloc[16:243]
        energy.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
        energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
        energy = energy.replace('...', np.nan)
        energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply'] * 1000000

        energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].replace(regex=True, to_replace=[r'\d', r' \(([^)]+)\)'], value=r'')
        energy = energy.replace('Republic of Korea', 'South Korea')
        energy = energy.replace('United States of America', 'United States')
        energy = energy.replace('United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland', 'United Kingdom')
        energy = energy.replace('China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region', 'Hong Kong')

        energy = energy.reset_index()
        energy = energy[['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']]
        return energy
```

And this line

```
        GDP = GDP.replace('Iran, Islamic Rep', 'Iran')
```

Change to this

```
        GDP = GDP.replace('Iran, Islamic Rep.', 'Iran')
```

The only `NaN` left is `Iran` at `2015`

Comment: after i remove that line, i can see 'Nan' in my result. add links of pictures of wanted and unwanted results! thanks for your advice!

Comment: No the problem is about that line, it's more about the excel file

Comment: I don't have a PC right now so I can't check it but I suppose you have `empty cell` or `NaN` or `...` in the excel

Comment: omg!! thank you!! i understand that the main problem is 'regular expression' code!

Comment: Also you misspell `'Iran, Islamic Rep.'`

Comment: And if my answer works, don't forget to mark it as Accepted